# Can't receive sms to mobile from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

I'm using twilio service in my rails app . I followed this [tutorial](http://www.heurion.com/blogs/ruby-on-rails-send-sms). But after i run the app the message is sent to my twilio account , but i did not received any message to my mobile, other than the code in the link. I just added this code in my routes.rb:

```
Sms::Application.routes.draw do
  get "send/sms"
  root 'send#sms'
end
```

Send controllers code :

```
   class SendController < ApplicationController
    def sms
      require 'rubygems'
      require 'twilio-ruby'
      @account_sid = 'AC6'
      @auth_token = '2bf'
      @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
      @client.account.sms.messages.create( :from => '(954) 740-8336',:to => '+919884667438',:body => 'Hey there!')
    end
   end
```

and my sms action html file contails this :

```
Your message was successfully sent .
```

Comment: There's no possible way to diagnose given the information you're providing.

Comment: @DaveNewton . sorry i now edited the question .

Comment: What happens? Are there any errors in the console or on the client? Etc. http://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install, http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest, and so on provide ways of diagnosing issues.

Comment: @DaveNewton .. No there are no errors . Its a successful execution but cant receive sms.

Comment: you are probably using a development account on Twilio, so you need to verify the number you use for testing and you'll be able to send sms only to verified numbers while in development mode, when you'll upgrade you can send to any numbers.

Comment: @John go to https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified and see if you have your number verified

Comment: Hey Twilio employee here. The first thing you need to check is if your account is a trial and your number is verified, as rmagnum2002 pointed out. Your own number should be verified when you signed up, but check https://twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified to make sure

Comment: If all else fails, our customer support team are brilliant at solving complex errors - https://twilio.com/help

Comment: @rmagnum2002 . yeah i checked it and my number is verified .

Comment: @phalt . yeah i submitted the problem to the team ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio employee here.

On further inspection into your code, I noticed you're trying to send an SMS to an Indian number. The telephone networks have a lot of restrictions in India, which all companies must abide by.

The reason you are not receiving your SMS messages is because all Indian numbers are automatically **opted-in to a Do Not Call Registry**. You will need to opt-out your number in order to receive SMS in India.

For more information about sending / receiving SMS messages in India, [check out our extensive FAQ section](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices)

You can get around this problem quickly by sending SMS to another non-Indian number, of course.